# python 3.6 list to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Need to write a function that takes a list of strings like

```
list =['taco', 'burger', 'hotdog']
```

then convert it to a dictionary where the keys are string location
and values are value one is the original string and value two is the number of character in string
dictionary should look something like this

```
dict = {'s0':taco, 4, 's1': 'burger', 5, 's3':'hotdog',6}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Shouldn't `s1` have the values `('burger', 6)`?

Comment: The output you've posted isn't syntactically valid. Also SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; you need to make an attempt at implementing this yourself.

Comment: the function should return the length of the strings as the second value I apparently can't count

Comment: Just use enumerate and len you can format it with `f` string...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to do this. You can get the index for the key with `enumerate`, and the number of characters in each string with `len`. Here, we create the keys with `'s' + str(index)`, and make the values a list `[item, len(item)]`.

```
>>> my_list = ['taco', 'burger', 'hotdog']
>>> {'s' + str(index): [item, len(item)] for index, item in enumerate(my_list)}
{'s0': ['taco', 4], 's1': ['burger', 6], 's2': ['hotdog', 6]}
```

Comment: will this return the values as tuples or would you need to pass them through tuple()

Comment: The values here are lists, but you can make them tuples if you like

Comment: Thank you for you help I am new to programing and python any feedback is a big help.